# Typescript tuple function arguments based on key

Tags: javascript, typescript, tuples

I'm writing types for my api which is based on tuples. I'm trying to infer the arguments of the function in this tuple.

For the sake of simplicity I've made a small example of what I'm roughly trying to achieve.

```
type InitType = ['init', (arg: string) => void]
type DestroyType = ['destroy', (arg: number) => void]
type GetType = ['get', () => void]

type Expected = InitType | DestroyType | GetType

// Expecting arg to be of type string
const test: Expected = ['init', (arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
}]

// Expecting arg to be of type number?
const test1: Expected = ['destroy', (arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
}]

// This does get checked tho..
const test2: Expected = ['get', () => {
    console.log(arg)
}]
```

Comment: What is problem?

Comment: The problem lies with the argument(s) of the fn not getting typed correctly. See this example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=47&pln=12&pc=39#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2AFXNAvFA2gcgY4HAGigAoBDAJwHMAuKAZ2Ev2oEop0A+KANwHsEAEwC6AKFCQoAEQhNK-EKimZcQuc0XEyVOlDgBXALYAjCJQ7c+g0RLRQA4hBT3VOas+2lLPAcPF2UgCiAB6QAMbAEEKcsATK0AA+MhoKSvbJTi6QYmIA9HlQoRHArFC6UMD8UGZQ-ABmlfbyrGLh-HBMlRr0xRCR0bG4+Eheuj5QAN5iULNQ7Z38ADYQAHRL-NQUNGxiAL4BBUVh-aVw1OU0ldW1DU1ShqbmAPxtHV1RTACMvScDMW51PItCRtuxODxpnN5u9lmsNltxvtDoVkAALBAMKBCfhyKAeYDzNH9ADWg2AaP4q1Wb06hM+wAATL8SoM3ASvBMoXMFgw4etNmDdgcxEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of December 2022, autocompletion for discriminated union of tuples is less powerful than for discriminated union of objects.

Compare with object-based union:

```ts
type InitType = {name: 'init', fn: (arg: string) => void}
type DestroyType = {name: 'destroy', fn: (arg: number) => void}
type GetType = {name: 'get', fn: () => void}

type Expected = InitType | DestroyType | GetType

// arg is string
const test: Expected = {name: 'init', fn: (arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
}}

// arg is number
const test1: Expected = {name: 'destroy', fn: (arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
}}

// arg is noit available
const test2: Expected = {name: 'get', fn: () => {
    console.log(arg) // Expected error
}}
```

There is an open issue addressing precisely your scenario [better autocompletion for dicriminated union as tuples #31977](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31977)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It’s been 4 years since that issue was opened. Guess I don’t have to get my hopes up 